# EntityFramework Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to do a `ToDictionary()` on my entities but I keep getting this error or another one similar like this one but with my entities shown in the message:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Or this one with my entity in the error msg:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'DataAccess.Posts'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

I broke the query down to some smaller peace's but still getting either of these error msgs:

```
var posts = dbContext
    .Posts
    .Where(x => channels.Contains(x.Connection))
    .DistinctBy(p => new { p.Medium, p.ID })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);

var asociatedTags = dbContext
    .PostTagRelation
    .Where(x => posts.Any(g => g.ItemId == x.ItemId && g.Medium == x.Medium)
        && x.Company == companyId)
    .Select(x => new { x.ItemId, x.Tags })
    .ToList();

Dictionary<string, Tags> dicTags = new Dictionary<string, Tags>();
dicTags = asociatedTags.ToDictionary(g => g.ItemId, g => g.Tags);
```

I came across a few posts about this, but I can't place them with my situation.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: If it is of any matter: `.DistinctBy()` is afaik no Out of the box method. Google says it comes with MoreLinq.

Comment: True, it's an extension on the `LINQ`.

Comment: `DistinctBy` is probably only an extension for LINQ-to-Objects (i.e. for `IEnumerable<T>`, not for `IQueryable<T>`). That means, calling it executes the DB query to this point and the result is a `posts` collection in memory which causes the exception in the second query at `posts.Any...`. Moreover it causes that sorting, `Skip` and `Take` are performed in memory and not in the database with much more loaded data than you need. I'd say, avoid `DistinctBy`.

Comment: If i lose the `DistinctBy` I'll get duplicate posts. What can I use in stead of `DistinctBy`?

Comment: Maybe something like: `GroupBy(p => new { p.Medium, p.ID }).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())`.

Comment: I'm selecting 20 records each time. Also, after the `GroupBy()` I can't order by x.Date because I get a compiler error about "System.Linq.IGrouping....... does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method ....... are you missing a reference?".

Comment: The OrderBy should be after `Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())` (which should give the first post in each group), not after the `GroupBy`.

Comment: That seems to be the trick Slauma! Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DistinctBy` (is it [this one](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs)?) is probably only an extension method for LINQ-to-Objects (i.e. for `IEnumerable<T>`, not for `IQueryable<T>`). That means, calling it executes the DB query to this point and the result is a `posts` collection in memory (not an `IQueryable<Post>`) which causes the exception in the second query at `posts.Any...` because with respect to the second SQL query `posts` is now a collection of "constant" objects which is not supported by LINQ-to-Entities. Moreover it causes that sorting, `Skip` and `Take` are performed in memory and not in the database with possible unnecessary overhead and much more loaded data than you need.

You can try to avoid `DistinctBy` and replace it by the following which should return `posts` as `IQueryable<Post>`:

```
var posts = dbContext
    .Posts
    .Where(x => channels.Contains(x.Connection))
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.Medium, p.ID })
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()) // gives the first Post in each group
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the `ToList()` call before the creation of the anonymous class (`Select(x => new { x.ItemId, x.Tags })`)

```
var dicTags= dbContext.PostTagRelation
   .Where(x => posts.Any(g => g.ItemId == x.ItemId && g.Medium == x.Medium)
       && x.Company == companyId)
   //force execution of the query
   .ToList() 
   //now you have an IEnumerable instead of IQueryable
   .ToDictionary(g => g.ItemId, g => g.Tags);
```